# Qt clearing an SQL query

Tags: qt

What is the difference between

```
void QSqlQuery::clear ()
```

and

```
void QSqlQuery::finish ()
```

Based on the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqlquery.html), I don't see what the diff is. What is the difference?  I'd like to know specifically when to use one over the other.

**EDIT - Some more elaboration and info from documentation.**
**clear()**
-Clears the result set and releases any resources held by the query.
 Sounds like finish() does the same...

-Sets the query state to inactive.
Finish does the same.

**finish()**
*-Instruct the database driver that no more data will be fetched from this query until it is re-executed.*
What does this mean specifically? What is the consequence of this?

*-It may be helpful in order to free resources such as locks or cursors if you intend to re-use the query at a later time.*
Doesn't clear do the same?  Doesn't clear release locks, cursors, etc?

*-Sets the query to inactive.*
clear does the same I believe.

-Bound values retain their values.
What is the point of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt comes with source code, you can see what's the difference by simply looking into the [qsqlquery.cpp file](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/d300e8208928084b62bbde01fb81bd66bc967bc8/src/sql/kernel/qsqlquery.cpp)

So according to the source code:

- clear - clears and resets the QSqlQuery object;
- finish - resets the [result](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsqlquery.html#result) member of the current query into inactive state;

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, I still have no idea what the difference is. The language used here is so generic and abstract that it doesn't mean anything to me. "Resets the result member" doesn't mean anything to me. If by this they mean the returned ressults (QSqlQuery also serves as an iterator), then doesn't .clear() do the same? I think so. Also, they both seem to set the query to inactive state. "Clears and resets the query" is different to finish() in what way? This is just gibberish by Nokia. I'd like to know when to use one over the other.

Comment: Those are different as clear resets entire object wheres finish resets only its result member. Qt documentation might be not clear enough, but (as I said) you always have the source code to look into, I believe it IS better then any documentation. Btw in both cases docs mention you should rarely if ever need to call these functions which explains why Qt team didn't spend a lot of time documenting them

Answer (score 2):

The language used to describe these functions is similar so it can definitely be a little confusing and I hope this explanation helps.  Here's how I interpret and use these methods.

```
void QSqlQuery::finish ()
```

I think of this as a way of saying I'm done with the query I just requested (eg no more reading/iterating) but I still plan on using that QSqlQuery object to do more work.  You're just releasing any memory/resources used to get the values from the previous query.  This really only makes a big, noticeable difference when you're dealing with large datasets over and over again, but I view it as good practice to use none the less.

```
void QSqlQuery::clear ()
```

This is my way of saying that I'm done with the QSqlQuery object and want to guarantee that none of the resources/memory I was using gets left around while I'm disposing of the object.  I rarely, if ever, use this as I've found that it's effectiveness can vary widely depending on the database you use and if you're using modern C++ features, it doesn't do a lot for you.

It's easier to understand the difference if you look at them as being written to solve a similar problem for two different time periods (eg old C code as opposed to modern C++).

They do very similar things but I'd recommend you just use **finish()**.

Answer (score 0):

For all, like me, that are wondering which method to invoke. I will share my research.

NOTE: I read the sources of the SQLite driver, so other databases drivers can be different.

- **finish()** resets the statement; in SQLite context it calls `sqlite3_reset`;
- **clear()** resets the whole **QSqlQuery** object; it clears bound values, prepared statement, lastError(), lastQuery() ..., sets the default options for all object's parameters; in SQLite context I think that `sqlite3_finalize` is also called;

So I should visualize it like that `finish < clear`. After **finish()** you could call exec() to reexecute the query, but after **clear()** you must prepere the query again and bind its values before you can successfully reexecute the query.